# Code fails to output errors or exceptions in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, nodegit

I am using a Node.JS library called GitNode. I don't think it's important but basically it's an API for git commands in Node.JS.

I have a piece of code whose purpose is to create a new branch in an existing repository. After running the code, I know it's not creating a repository, and I also know it's not working correctly.

This is the entirety of my code:

```
var Git = require("nodegit");

var getMostRecentCommit = function(repository) {
  return repository.getBranchCommit("master");
};

var makeBranch = function(respository) {
  console.log("in here1")
  repository.createBranch("tester", getMostRecentCommit(repository)).then(
      function(reference) {
           console.log("good")},               // if it works
      function(reasonForFailure) {
           console.log("bad_error")})          // createBranch has error case
      .catch(function(reasonForFailure) {
           console.log("bad_catch")});         // if the error function fails, I also have a catch statement
};


Git.Repository.open("../test_repo")
  .then(makeBranch);
```

I've placed a lot of catch statements in the hopes of finding my error. But I can't seem to output anything. Neither the phrase "Bad_error" or "Bad_catch" output.

I know the code is broken and that createBranch isn't working. I tested some code that was supposed to run after I called `repository.createBranch`, but it never runs where as anything before createBranch is called will run. This indicates that CreateBranch is the problem.

So why are my errors not being caught?

**Edit**

I've fixed the code and it outputs the error (see answer below), but I'm still wondering why my other exceptions/error statements failed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out part of the problem thanks to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569913/switch-branch-tag-with-nodegit)

I just had to add a catch statement to my Repository.open() function.

```
var makeBranch = function(respository) {
  console.log("in here1")
  repository.createBranch("tester", getMostRecentCommit(repository)).then(
      function(reference) {
           console.log("good")},               
      function(reasonForFailure) {
           console.log("bad_error")})          
      .catch(function(reasonForFailure) {
           console.log("bad_catch")});        
};


Git.Repository.open("../test_repo")
  .then(makeBranch).catch(
  function(reasonForFailure) {console.log("bad")}); // This Works
```

If anyone is curious, turns out I was passing in the variable `respository` instead of `repository` :p

And this will output `bad`. So that's good. I'm still not quite why this worked but my other catch statement didn't. I'm still looking for a good answer or explanation.